# Getting entity framework context in Linqpad?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linqpad

I've created a `DLL` assembly which contains the `edmx` for `northwind` database.

I created a reference to that dll through linqpad and I do see the db and able to run queries.

But - I want to test the behavior of `DeferredLoadingEnabled` property and I need to set it via the context variable.

eg

```
ctx.DeferredLoadingEnabled = false;
```

But how can I access `ctx`?

linqpad generates it for me , and I need to access it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In Entity Framework 5, the equivalent property is:

```
ctx.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
```

If you're in LINQPad, you're already in the context, so you can just say:

```
Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
```

But when I'm copying code from Visual Studio to LINQPad, I'll often just add a line at the top so all the code works the same:

```
var ctx = this;
```

Comment: But if I set it to false  - it doesnt yield the orders ... http://i.stack.imgur.com/Nu0Y5.png . how can I make it show the orders ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir: Disabling Lazy Loading is not the same as forcing Eager Loading. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/3730555/120955

Answer (score 5):

When using Linqpad, you are acually *inside* the ObjectContext. 
Just type:

```
this.
```

and you can access the properties on *your* ObejctContext.

(also: make sure you use "C# Statement")

Comment: just a sec :) im booting up my machine

Comment: hmm my EF model doesn't have `DeferredLoadingEnabled` are you sure it shoud be directly on the ObejctContext - maybe is in the `ContextOptions` property

Comment: http://books.google.co.il/books?id=t1de8nSVYnkC&pg=PA362&lpg=PA362&dq=%22You+can+make+EF+behave+like+L2S+and+have+it+populate%22&source=bl&ots=24udQsLg3H&sig=boyr3QG0Lb6K_igKU8kQjDqPRUg&hl=en&sa=X&ei=5NBBUrK5L9DasgbYt4CQAw&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22You%20can%20make%20EF%20behave%20like%20L2S%20and%20have%20it%20populate%22&f=false

Answer (score 5):

There is no `DeferredLoadingEnabled` property in `Entity Framework` - it is part of `Linq to SQL`, not `Linq to entities` (EF).

Entity Framework has deferred loading by default. The linked tables will be loaded on access or when you explicitly load them yourself or when you load them directly with the first resource (eager loading).

Comment: +1 for pointing out there is no `DeferredLoadingEnabled` property on the `ObjectContext` :)

Comment: am i blind ? http://books.google.co.il/books?id=t1de8nSVYnkC&pg=PA362&lpg=PA362&dq=%22You+can+make+EF+behave+like+L2S+and+have+it+populate%22&source=bl&ots=24udQsLg3H&sig=boyr3QG0Lb6K_igKU8kQjDqPRUg&hl=en&sa=X&ei=5NBBUrK5L9DasgbYt4CQAw&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22You%20can%20make%20EF%20behave%20like%20L2S%20and%20have%20it%20populate%22&f=false

Comment: @RoyiNamir you are properly not bind. but L2S is Linq to SQL, *not* Linq to Entities

Comment: I know.but it says : "you can make EF behave like l2s"...xx.DeferredLoadingEnabled =true; maybe I dont understand the line there ??

Comment: @RoyiNamir EF behaves like L2S, when you set this property to true in L2S. If you don't set it to true, EF does not behave like it. But the sentence in the book is really written very confusing.

Comment: So does the incremental DB quries are  done automatically **according** to the `projection` of the query  || `Include` || join... ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir: If you use `Include`, then the navigation properties are loaded in the same DB round-trip as the original. Likewise, if you include both the element and its property in your `Select` projection (i.e. `.Select(e => new{e, e.Things})`, the property will be populated automatically. Otherwise, as soon as you access the property, Entity Framework will attempt to load it from the database. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx for more details.